# HelpBallon.js in ASP.NET UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

Does someone know, how to get the HelpBallon.js (http://www.beauscott.com/2008/03/02/helpballoonjs-version-20/) work in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel? After a postback all images are lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know this plugin, but the general idea is that you need to make update of the javascript after the Panel is loaded.

I check the code of HeloBallon plugin and see that is capture the `onload`, and run the `registerClassLinks` function.

**To run it again when the panel is updated you can use this javascript code on your page.**

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();    
prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);

function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {      
}

function EndRequest(sender, args) {
    HelpBalloon.registerClassLinks();
}
```

Now you need to check if this works, or you need to make some small changes, but this is the idea.

Comment: Your answer gave me the right direction:

I definded an element as a placeholder in the page: 
<span id="myContainer"></span>

And then following code at the end of the page:

<script type="text/javascript">
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(Page_Loaded);
function Page_Loaded(sender, args) {
      var hb1 = new HelpBalloon({ returnElement: true, title: 'title', content: 'text' });
      $get('myContainer').appendChild(hb1.icon);
    }
  </script>

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working solution:

Define a container where to place the image:

```
<span id="myContainer"></span>
```

and then add the following code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(Page_Loaded);

    function Page_Loaded(sender, args) {
      var hb1 = new HelpBalloon({ returnElement: true, title: 'title', content: 'text.' });
      $get('myContainer').appendChild(hb1.icon);
    }

    }
  </script>
```